# Refactoring using generics

Tags: c#, .net

I have few function with the same kind of procedure when only Object does changes.
I've tried to write generic function to that group of methods but failed to get ID of T.

Can you help me refactor this ?

```
List<ObjectOfSomeKind> allObjects = new List<ObjectOfSomeKind>() { new ObjectOfSomeKind{ ID = 1}, new ObjectOfSomeKind { ID = 2 }};
List<ObjectOfSomeKind> objects = new List<ObjectOfSomeKind>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count(); i++)
            {
                int id = ids.ElementAt(i);
                ObjectOfSomeKind object = allObjects .Where(item => item.ID.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefault();
                if (object == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("error");
                }

                objects.Add(object);
            }
```

Comment: `new Object { ID = 1}` is not valid.. unless you created a class named 'Object'?  In which case, don't do that..

Comment: Object = ObjectOfSomeKind

Comment: Naming is very much a key skill for programmers.  Good idea to learn it, and fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define interface (or base class) with ID property

```
public interface IEntity
{
   int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Implement this interface by your classes

```
public class Foo : IEntity
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then either use `IEntity` in your code, or (if you want to use generics) add constraint to your generic class or method

```
where T : IEntity
```

UPDATE if all your classes have ID property, you also can use `dynamic` objects (sometimes it is also solution, but I prefer compile time checks):

```
List<dynamic> allObjects = new List<dynamic>() { 
    new ObjectOfSomeKind{ ID = 1}, new ObjectOfSomeKind { ID = 2 }};
List<dynamic> objects = new List<dynamic>();

for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count(); i++)
{
    int id = ids.ElementAt(i);
    dynamic obj = allObjects.Where(item => item.ID.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (obj == null)                
        throw new Exception("error");                

    objects.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Yep, this was my first thought but is there anyway to avoid common interface ?

Comment: @eugeneK nope, there is no legal way (I mean without reflection). In order to have common property, classes should have common interface (or base class)

Comment: @eugeneK actually there is also `dynamic` (sorry, forgot about that).